# Java Cipher Game : Decryption using HashMap

Tags: java

In my cipher game in java I'm having trouble with the decryption part. I want the user to be able to enter the letter they would like another letter in the sentence to be replaced with. For example, the user enters "li" and all of the letters 'l' is replaces with 'i'.

My code below decrypts all of the sentence and doesn't allow the user to do the work themselves. How do I do fix this?
The new letters encrypted should also be in uppercase.

The variable subTable is just all the letters printed of what they're getting substitutioned with. The String encrypted is the function for encrypting the text which I already finished.

```
    public static String decryptString(Map<Character,Character> subTable, String encrypted,String input) {
    
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("\nEnter the letter of the sentence and what letter you would like to substiture it with: ");
    input = in.next();
    
    Map<Character, Character> subTableInversed = subTable.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getValue, Map.Entry::getKey));
    StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();

        for ( char character : encrypted.toCharArray())
        {
            sb2.append(subTableInversed.get(character));
        }
        String decrypted = sb2.toString();
        return decrypted;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand how this program should work, because when you start to replace a specific character with another one, what will happen to the real ones? For example let's say I want the program to replace "I" with "C", so what should the real "C" be interpreted as. Also I don't quite unterstand what you want the user to do

Comment: For example the word is "Hello". The encrypted word is "ipuum" ( h = i, p = e, l = u, o = m". When the user enters "ul" the word would become "ipLLm"

Comment: You could use the String replace method to do this. But in that case at general you should think about storing which characters have been modified and which not. Then it wouldn't be possible to encode it without any information, but provide that info it needs and it will be a program that works. Because like I already said, what will happen to the characters that shouldn't be modified but are used to map another char.

Comment: yeah i tried that but I need the game to pick our random letters out of the alphabet every time the game starts. The string replace method wont be able to change letters every time

Comment: what should happen to the real characters? You know what i mean